# Higher order Procedures in delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

I am attempting to reference a procedure as a parameter of another procedure and am having trouble understanding the documentation.(http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Procedural_Types_(Delphi))

From what I understood I need to create a new type for the procedure..

```
type
  TCallback = procedure of object;
```

and declare the higher order procedure as
`procedure HigherOrder(pProc: TCallback);`

I receive the compilation error " E2010 Incompatible types: 'TCallBack' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter' " when attempting to call the function(when the button is clicked)

```
type
  TCallBack = procedure of object;
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    btnAct: TButton;
    procedure btnActClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure HigherOrder(pProc: TCallback);
    procedure Callback();
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TfrmMain }

procedure TfrmMain.btnActClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HigherOrder(Callback()); <--Error occurs here
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Callback;
begin
  //Do some stuff
end;

procedure TfrmMain.HigherOrder(pProc: TCallback);
begin
  //Do some other stuff
  pProc();
end;

end.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am quite new to programming in delphi.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are *calling* `Callback()` first and then trying to pass its *return value* (which, it doesn't have one) to `HigherOrder()`, but that is not what `HigherOrder()` is expecting, which is why you are getting the error. In other words, your code is *roughly equivalent* to this:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMain.btnActClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //HigherOrder(Callback());
  var res := Callback();
  HigherOrder(res);
end;
```

Except that the type of `res` is *undefined* since `Callback()` is a `procedure` and not a `function`.

When calling `HigherOrder()`, you need to remove the trailing `()` parenthesis from `Callback()` in order to pass `Callback` *itself* (well, its memory address, anyway) as the value of the `pProc` parameter, eg:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMain.btnActClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HigherOrder(Callback);
end;
```

Yes, you can also drop the parenthesis when *calling* a procedure without passing any parameters to it. But, in this case, the compiler is smart enough to know that the parenthesis-omitting `Callback` identifier is being assigned to a closure type and so will *pass it as-is* and not *call it*.